# Error When Populating JTable from Vectors

Tags: java, swing, vector, jtable

I am trying to populate a table from a text file using vectors.  Should I be creating a new vector for each row? Is there anything else that appears wrong with my code?  I'm not quite sure what to do from here.

```
public class myJTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
        Vector<Vector<String>> rowData = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

        //String splitting
        try {
            FileReader fReader = new FileReader("lakedata.txt");
            BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(fReader);
            String input;
            String[] temp;

            while((input=inFile.readLine())!=null) {
                temp = input.split(",",3);
                for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {
                    v.addElement(temp[i]);
                    System.out.println(temp[i]);
                    }

                System.out.println(v);
                rowData.addElement(v);
                }

            inFile.close();
            } 

        catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");    
        }

        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        columnNames.addElement("Depth");
        columnNames.addElement("Temperature");
        columnNames.addElement("D.O.");
        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(500,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Create a new vector for each row.

Comment: Where should I be creating the new vector at? Inside the while loop?

Comment: Yes. Just before the `for` loop.

Comment: @LeeMeador I can't seem to get the code formatted properely in the comment box, but I am getting an exception and the program is terminating on run with the table and vectors unpopulated after placing the creation of a new vector just before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Vector, you can create a [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) then set it as the model of the table, then invoke its `addRow` method to directly put the read line result to the table. The table will automatically update itself when data to a table is added.

I took the liberty to revise your code into a cleaner one.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TablePopulation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {

                JTable table = new JTable();
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

                /* Set the table data to null first since 
                 * we will fetch data from file line by line
                 * -------------------------------------- */
                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null, new String[]{"Depth","Temperature","D.O."});
                table.setModel(model);

                /* String splitting
                 * ---------------- */
                try {
                    FileReader fReader = new FileReader("file.txt");
                    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(fReader);
                    String input = inFile.readLine();

                    while(input !=null) {
                        String[] temp = input.split(",");
                        model.addRow(temp);

                        input = inFile.readLine();
                    }

                    inFile.close();
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setSize(500,300);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also, atleast put `e.printStackTrace()` (since you're not using any logging framework) in the catch block to see the stack trace of what's going on in case some error has been caught.