# Trying to create a JTable with 2D vector and string array header, how do I do it?

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jtable

I'm returning errors from JTable inserting a 2D vector and a String[] as header...

```
try
    {
        refreshVector();
    }
    catch (Exception j)
    {
        throw j;
    }

    String[] headers = {"ID","Brand", "Item", "Details", "Qty", "Code", "re-order"};

    JTable tbl_display = new JTable(data, headers);
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tbl_display);
    scrollpane.setBounds(120,120,600,300);
```

refreshVector method contains...

```
public void refreshVector() throws Exception
{
    dbconnect conn = new dbconnect();

    try
    {
        conn.connect();
    }
    catch (Exception p)
    {
        throw p;
    }

    rs = conn.getData();

    while(rs.next())
    {
        Vector<Object> vec = new Vector<Object>();
        vec.add(rs.getString("ID_product"));
        vec.add(rs.getString("brand"));
        vec.add(rs.getString("description"));
        vec.add(rs.getString("details"));
        vec.add(rs.getString("quantity"));
        vec.add(rs.getString("product_code"));
        vec.add(rs.getString("reorder"));
        data.addElement(vec);
    }
}
```

Do I have to use a table model? I'm just trying to create a simple table displaying the results of my search in the database. Is there a way to go about this without going into table models and use the standard table constructor. Thank you.

Comment: _Do I have to use a table model?_ Yes, for [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever - that's the exclusive responsibility of the LayoutManager

Answer (score 1):

*Do I have to use a table model?*

Yes, the relevant [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) includes several examples. In the particular case of database access, consider `SwingWorker`, as outlined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish%28V...%29).

As an aside, use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) rather than `setBounds()`.

Comment: thanks.. ok.. I've read that in the past I'm still a bit confused but I'll try to understand it more.. but last question is should I use a default table model because I am using a vector of vector..? thanks

Comment: I found an answered question.. thanks.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576642/error-when-populating-jtable-from-vectors?rq=1)

Comment: I'm having a hard time configuring a layout manager to fit any of my UI designs so I just used null layout and setBounds my components... I think it may not be good practice but it works... it's just difficult to design UI based on the provided layouts by java... just in case what Layout Manager do you often use for your applications..? GridLayout was really hard to resize... gridbaglayout I guess would fit but I have yet to be more learned on it...

Comment: @buencamino: Glad you got it sorted; for reference, the tutorial examples show common layout usage.